# correlated random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that X~Normal(m1, var1) and Y~Normal(m2,var2) and X and Y are correlated. Is this true to conclude that Z=[X|X>0]+Y is a normal variable with the following parameters:

Mean=integral(x.f(x),0,inf)+m2

and

Variance=(Var(X|X>0))+var2+2Cov(X,Y|X>0)

? thanks to all

Comment: What is [X|X>0] in Z=[X|X>0]+Y?

Answer (score 1):

$\Pr(Y \le y)$ may not be the same as $\Pr(Y \le y|X \gt 0)$ since we know $X$ and $Y$ are correlated.  So $E[Y]$ may not be the same as $E[Y|X \gt 0]$.

This means that you **cannot** say $E[X+Y|X\gt 0] = E[X|X\gt 0] + E[Y]$.

You **can** say $E[X+Y|X\gt 0] = E[X|X\gt 0] + E[Y|X\gt 0]$.